# RSA key related error when trying to use the DocuSign API

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am trying to use "api_client.request_jwt_user_token" in the DocuSign API. But I'm not sure how to convert the RSA PEM file:

```
import rsa
from docusign_esign import ApiClient

with open('docusign.pem', mode='rb') as privatefile:
    keydata = privatefile.read()
privkey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(keydata)
key1 = privkey.save_pkcs1(format='DER')

api_client = ApiClient()
api_client.host = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'
access_token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...etc'
api_client.set_default_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +
                              access_token)
client_id = '2e65...etc'
user_id = 12341234
oauth_host_name = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'
private_key_bytes = key1
expires_in = 28800
result = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(client_id, user_id,
                                           oauth_host_name,
                                           private_key_bytes,
                                           expires_in)
```

I get a Python exception in the API call:

```
Could not deserialize key data.
```

This is in "site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py"

I'm guessing there is an easier way to get the RSA PEM file into the API.

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/rsa/

**Update**

I also tried converting the PEM file using openssl and then reading that in instead:

(command prompt)

```
$ openssl rsa -inform pem -in docusign.pem -outform der -out docusign.der
```

The resulting file is 1192 bytes.

(code)

```
with open('docusign.der', mode='rb') as privatefile:
    key1 = privatefile.read()
```

Which leads to the same error.

**Update 2**

I tried without any conversion on the key and also with a different setting, now I get a different error:

```
oauth_host_name = 'account-d.docusign.com'
```

Returns bad HTTP:

```
Exception Value: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 
'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; 
charset=utf-8', 'Expires': '-1', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken':
'666633df-ac84-4193-a282-e81075302413', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 
'nosniff', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; 
includeSubDomains; preload, max-age=15768000', 'X-Frame-Options': 
'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block;
report=/client-errors/xss', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'SE1DFE2', 'Date':
'Sat, 22 Aug 2020 18:53:16 GMT', 'Content-Length': '27'})
HTTP response body: b'{"error":"invalid_request"}'
```

It doesn't seem to give much clue as to what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, you obtain the RSA private key from the DocuSign eSignature settings tool (formerly known as the eSignature admin tool). Use the Integrations / API and Keys screen.

DocuSign has an enhancement request ID-4714 that will enable developers to upload their key pair's public key to DocuSign. But at this time you *download* the private key from DocuSign for creating the JWT.

### Added

Unfortunately, the [request_jwt_user_token](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/blob/master/docusign_esign/client/api_client.py#L665) method is only documented in the source. Here are my comments on your call to the method:

- For the `private_key_bytes` attribute, use the downloaded private key as a simple ASCII string (with real new lines). In other words, its value should be something like

this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAkbz3bi31zrH2ry4p8S4ncPoMdkUyu+MG46m9BalOKzWNNAvW
1LVs5ftlXxzA6V0m6nx895w8S761/qZ8xtAAl99DezRn/3CueeBUyw+tvlmEBu1C
IJK69GVoSInIKf6qyeL1WxxFV5R17QtIiQeT2yCa/fitCaxwxkNlYpP4wd5tcG0W
pNHUqbQmWywTRMIBa6yYMc9qvDTJpOubrTal3BI8VqmBww0diFWLm4l6+IZ7QvDV
Q48JYErfywNXyYTxZ4kugQcuNDR3vSuwR3KSlmiRcfhkn+2jb5rx6kKnZjXQLhg3
...
PEHgznlGh/vUboCuA4tQOcKytxFfKG4F+jM/g4GH9z46KZOow3Hb6g==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

- Max life for a JWT produced access token is 1 hour, so use 3600 for the `expires_in` value
- `user_id` is the **guid** for the use who will be impersonated. Obtain the this value from either the eSignature settings tool in the Users section or the "API & Keys" screen for your own value.
- You need to specify the `scopes` parameter: use `signature`

Comment: OK, but the downloaded (from DocuSign) key is in PEM format. What format does the API call for the JWT take, and how do I convert to that format?

Comment: See updated answer. The call wants the PEM format as is.